# How do I output html <span> text without id?

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that will be able to output definitions and syllables for words. So far I've got this code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    Label1.Text = ""
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("f1word").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Search" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

And now I want to be able to output the element that is holding the syllables and definition into a label. How do I do that?